# Snap mode on Dual Monitor Displays?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, display

How do snap an application like a web browser on individual displays?  Now one display don't have snap mode to the right and the other screen does not have snap mode to the left. They are on Linux Mint Debian Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but you can use keyboard shortcuts which will snap the way you want with dual displays.

Keyboard shortcuts can be found by searching 'keyboard' in the menu, navigating to the shortcuts tab, it's then under 'Windows' and 'Tiling and Snapping'.

Good luck.